# jquery (or pure js) simulate enter key pressed for testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, mocking

What the best way to simulate the user pressing "enter"? $(element).keypress() doesn't seem to allow me to pass in the actual key that was pressed.

This is for unit testing.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/)

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 13;
$("#theInputToTest").trigger(e);
```

Comment: Thanks redsquare. This solution wasn't obvious to me from the docs -- http://api.jquery.com/trigger/. They show they usage as .trigger( eventType, extraParameters ). Should I have been able to figure that out based on the docs? Is this an officially supported feature.

Comment: @morgancodes, I guess not easily no, it is not explained but hinted at lower down.

Comment: the demo script is poor. check the key used and verify it's the expected key, to be complete.

Comment: @Luke Stanley, Thanks for the dig luke - "jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code".

Comment: The prior test code is different, test and setup are combined. http://jsfiddle.net/yB78c/ try this better test, with and without the keyCode - you will see the bug. What's a dig?

Comment: I find jQuery's documentation to be quite a mess too, sometimes I feel they're purposely trying to make it harder to get information. This page of theirs did have some clearer examples though: https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: @redsquare What if i don't want to use jquery?
Is there any javascript alternative?

Answer (score 101):

For those who want to do this in pure javascript, look at:

### Using standard KeyboardEvent

As Joe comment it, [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) is now the standard.

Same example to fire an enter (keyCode 13):

```
const ke = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13
});
document.body.dispatchEvent(ke);
```

You can use [this page](https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) help you to find the right keyboard event.

---

**Outdated answer**:

- [initKeyboardEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE9+, Chrome and Safari
- [initKeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initKeyEvent) for Firefox

You can do something like (here for Firefox)

```
var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
// Send key '13' (= enter)
ev.initKeyEvent(
    'keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0);
document.body.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: Looks like this answer needs updating. KeyboardEvent is standard now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent (initKeyEvent is deprecated)

Comment: Can you answer this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137575/simulate-pressing-enter-key-on-input-text  I thought about copying your answer but I figured you would want to answer it yourself.

Comment: const ke = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13
});document.querySelectorAll('.search')[0].dispatchEvent(ke);