# How to fire the actual "Enter" keypress event of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I know it is possible to use `JQuery.Event` to simulate "Enter" keypress. Something like this does that -

```
var event = jQuery.Event( "keydown" );
event.keyCode = 13
$("input").trigger( event );
```

However, this does not fire the browser default behavior when the actual "Enter" key is pressed. For example, going to next line if the cursor is in `textarea` or submitting the form when the cursor is in `input` tag.

I want to know if it is possible to trigger or simulate the actual "Enter" keypress event/behavior.

Comment: It would be easier to trigger whatever is supposed to happen when you press the enter key, rather than fake that.  Explain specifically what you want to achieve and we can help.

Comment: Actually I just want to know if its possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/)

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13 
$("#test").keypress(function(){
   alert('keypress triggered')
}).trigger(e)
```

Comment: Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing

Comment: this doesn't trigger browsers native event.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want some thing similar this one?

```
 $(function(){
   $(document).keypress(function(event) {
      if(event.which == 13) {
      console.log("Dude! You hit Enter Key!!");
     }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:

```
$("body").delegate("input", "keypress",function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
  }
}
```

it's work for all input .