# Press the enter key in a text box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

How can I mimic pressing the enter button from within a `<input>`, using jQuery?

In other words, when a `<input>` (type text) is in focus and you press enter, a certain event is triggered. How can I trigger that event with jQuery?

There is no form being submitted, so `.submit()` won't work

**EDIT**

Okay, please listen carefully, because my question is being misinterpreted. I do NOT want to trigger events WHEN the enter button is pressed in textbox. I want to *simulate* the enter button being pressed inside the textbox, and trigger this from jQuery, from `$(document).ready`. So no method involving `on.('keypress')...` or stuff like that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing

Comment: @MarcoPrins ok just let me now what you wish aftersimulating the enter button being press , do u wish to call  any function after that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `keypress` then check the keycode

Try this

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code==13){
        // Enter pressed... do anything here...
    }
});
```

OR

```
e = jQuery.Event("keypress")
e.which = 13 //choose the one you want
    $("#test").keypress(function(){
     alert('keypress triggered')
    }).trigger(e)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for @Sridhar R . This will fire events when enter is pressed. I want to **press** enter (effectively) with jQuery

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('input').trigger(
  jQuery.Event('keydown', { which: 13 })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `.trigger()` .Docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `{which:13}` try using `{keyCode:13}`.

$('input').trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {keyCode:13}));

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); this will help understand how to answer questions. Please, provide more information about what your solution is working on in that case.