# Simulate <enter> keypress in javascript to trigger a form-submit

Tags: javascript

I've found a dozen different SO articles on how to do this, but none of them are working.

I'm trying to write some tests, and I want to test that when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> in an `input`, the form does indeed post back.  However, I can't get it to simulate this.

No matter which method I choose, the `keypress` event is being triggered--event listeners see it--but the form isn't being submitted.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pks337w7/1/):

#### Html

```
<!-- returns an error on submit, but that's fine... 
     we're only seeing if we can get a submit to happen -->
<form action="POST">
    <input id="myinput" type='text' value="foo" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(function () {
    var $input = $("#myinput");
    $input.on("keypress", function (evt) {
        $("#output").append("Typed: " + evt.keyCode + ", but the form didn't submit.<br>");
    });

    $("form").on("submit", function () { alert("The form submitted!"); } );

    // try jQuery event
    var e = $.Event("keypress", {
        keyCode: 13
    });
    $input.trigger(e);

    // try vanilla javascript
    var input = $input[0];
    e = new Event("keypress");
    e.keyCode = 13;
    e.target = input;
    input.dispatchEvent(e);

    e = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    e.initEvent("keypress", true, true);
    e.keyCode = 13;
    e.target = input;
    input.dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

Is it possible to simulate an actual keypress like this?

If you focus on the text box (in jsFiddle) and physically press <kbd>enter</kbd>, the page will post back and will return something like:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve, only in code.

Here's why:

```
$("input").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I ran into this in my code base, and I want to test that this sort of thing doesn't happen again.

Comment: i got three times "Typed: 13" when i just call your link on osx with chrome, ff and safari...so looks like its working?

Comment: Focus on the textbox and actually press <enter>... *That's* the behavior I'm looking for

Comment: The keypress is working but i 'think' he's saying that the form submission which happens when you 'press' the enter button manually is not being sent.. i think this is a security thing. Stopping you from auto posting forms perhaps? I'll go and look.

Comment: @KevinCJones If that is what he is trying to do, using `form.submit()` is the way.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, that works fine, as does finding the button and running `.click()`.  But that is not what I'm trying to test.

Comment: It works fine for me. A popup saying the form was submitted then i was redirected to a page.

Comment: @jakekimds It does that without manually clicking and pressing enter?

Comment: @dfoverdx It does it when I click on the box then press enter.

Comment: @jakekimds Yes, I want to do it automatically with javascript.

Comment: I don't **think** you can do it, but if this is for user simulation e.g. tests, as you put it, i think you could just do any of your examples but simply capture that keycode 13 was clicked and call the submit function instead...

If this was purely an academic excercise, i've even looked into this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18937620/4682576 but didn't find any joy..

Comment: @KevinCJones Yeah, that's kind of the conclusion I was drawing.  It's unfortunate, because I actually ran into a case where some ridiculous code caught the keypress event and if the keycode was 13, it prevented bubbling.

Comment: @dfoverdx Not mine, but it might help: http://jsfiddle.net/DxER9/. The plugin part

Comment: @jakekimds Yeah, tried that one already :)

Answer (score -2):

To simulate the [keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) on the input we have to use the [KeyboardEvent constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) and pass the event to the input's [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method.

```js
const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
  view: window,
  keyCode: 13,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});

document.querySelector("input").dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<!-- returns an error on submit, but that's fine... 
     we're only seeing if we can get a submit to happen -->
<form action="POST">
    <input id="myinput" type='text' value="foo" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

You can see more information on [mdn documentation on triggering and creating events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: I added your method to the OP jsfiddle.  It, too, fails to submit the form. http://jsfiddle.net/pks337w7/10/