# Ability to auto create chip when focus of PrimFaces p:chips is left

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using a [`p:chips`-component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml) in my JSF-based application.

I was researching, if it is possible to modify the behavior of this component in such a way, that leaving the `input`-element would add any remaining text content as a new chip for pretty much the same reasons that are given in [this issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4218), that requested the same functionality for the corresponding for primeng-component:

> **What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?**
>   Easier for the users to use when they're only entering a single value and it may be the first time using the control. Reduces the possibility of unexpected behavior as the control then will effectively behave like an input text box.

Seeing that the issue has been resolved for primeng, it stands to reason, that it was a valid request.

Can the same result be achieved for PrimeFaces?

---

I've found a workaround and will post it as my own answer, because

1. it may help someone else who wants the same feature and
2. it may be considered to be a bit of a botch and someone might find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to achieve the requested behavior by adding an `onblur`-listener (which is the aptly named counterpart to an `onfocus`) to the `p:chips`-component that [simulates hitting [enter]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137833/5483217) when leaving the `input`-element.

By assigning a `widgetVar` to the `p:chips`-component it is possible to retrieve the actual `input`-element of the created widget in a client side script using `PF('<widgetVar-identifier>').input[0]` (*which relies on a undocumented API and may therefore break in a future update*). An artificial `keydown`-event for *enter* (key code `13`) can then be dispatched to the `input`-element which triggers the default behavior of `p:chips` of adding the current text content as a new chip.

Here is an appropriately configured `p:chips`component:

```
<p:chips
  id="chips"
  widgetVar="pf-chips"
  value="#{pringlesBean.chips}"
  onblur="
    var e = document.createEvent('Event');
    e.initEvent('keydown');
    e.keyCode = 13;
    e.which = 13;
    PF('pf-chips').input[0].dispatchEvent(e);
  "
/>
```