# How to simulate pressing enter key inside an input field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects, xss, dom-events

I am trying to create a client side Javascript tool that checks for DOM XSS vulnerability for the input fields that are there in web page.

What I am doing right now is trying to find out the element inside the page with input tag.

Then I am changing their value to some malicious string say `alert("hi")` then I want to simulate pressing enter key inside the input element so that it got submitted,After that I will check if my malicious script has got executed or not. I need to do this via Javascript, is there any way to do this? I tried the following code but it does not seem to work.

```
inputField = document.getElementsByTagNameNS("*",'input')
var e = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
if (e.initKeyboardEvent) {  // Chrome, IE
e.initKeyboardEvent("keyup", true, true, document.defaultView, "Enter", 0, 
"", false, "");
} else { // FireFox
e.initKeyEvent("keyup", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, 
false, false, 13, 0);
}

inputField[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

It is not getting submitted.Currently I have to find the next input element that has the type "submit", I am assuming this one is the submit part for the input field and doing a `click()` on it.but this approach is not foolproof, it might pick a wrong element and click on it.How should I do it ?

Kindly help, stuck big time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery (or pure js) simulate enter key pressed for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing)

Comment: Why does it need to be a keypress? Just do `inputField[0].form.submit()`. No events required.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi, You saved my day