# I want to press enter key by programmatically when user do some stuff in js

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to simulate an *enter key* press in JavaScript when the user does some stuff?

Comment: Yes.https://www.google.com/search?q=js+trigger+keypress&oq=js+trigger+keypress

Comment: Using jquery, then doing a dispatch

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Is jQuery capable to search too?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536939(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //enter keycode
e.keyCode = 13;
$("#theInputToTest").trigger(e);
```

The `trigger` function simulate an event (for example a click, a key pressed...).

More information [here](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

There is a question like yours with answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing).

Comment: Is there any way to do it in pure js or in angularjs ?

Comment: See this answer for pure JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937620/188837 
Angular which version?