# How can I press ENTER by execute_script in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textarea, submit

I have this piece of code:

```
f=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf")
(driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", f, "Hi!"))
```

The word "Hi!" is sent in the box. But, I could not press ENTER to send it. It is notifiable that `send_keys()` and `submit()` doesn't work in my code.

Comment: Did you try to send `Keys.ENTER`? You can also try to pass [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276794/jquery-or-pure-js-simulate-enter-key-pressed-for-testing/18937620#18937620) to `driver.execute_script()`

Comment: @ Andersson When I use your suggestion, this error is presented:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Did you use it as `f.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`?

Comment: @ Andersson This solution is faced to this error:
Element <textarea class="_bilrf"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: I had told that send_keys() is not worked on my code.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/p/BgdhsyvgWCi/?taken-by=asarokh

Comment: try f.send_keys(u'\ue007')
this is the ENTER's code.

Comment: It doesn't work too. This error is happened too:
Element <textarea class="_bilrf"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: I guess that we should use execute_script. Did you have idea?

Comment: Can you share my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/a[2]/span""").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf").send_keys("Hi!", Keys.ENTER)
```