# Simulate Enter key in userscript tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to write a userscript that types something in input tag with class name="chat-input" and presses enter.The userscript as of now only types "Hello!" in chat-input but does not simulate enter key. Any idea why?

```
var msg = "Hello!";

        var target = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-input")[0];
                             target.value = msg ;
        var eventType = "textInput";
        var evt = document.createEvent("TextEvent");
        evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 13);

        target.focus();
        target.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The input box does not have any submit button only way to send message is by enter key

Answer (score 3):

Copying the answer with modification from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937620/1988220).

```
const ke = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13
});
target.dispatchEvent(ke);
```

According to that post, `initKeyEvent` is only for Firefox.

Comment: If a post is a duplicate, you should vote to close, not copy the same answer

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't see the question as a duplicate question, they just had the same answer. But yeah, if you say so