# Simulating an Enter key in an Input using javascript and Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a script for Tampermonkey that will insert in a Text input the text from a selected item in a dropdown menu and simulate the Enter key being pressed so the event assigned to that input will be triggered.

This is how I defined my test `input`,

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Topics" id="TText" onkeydown="checkEnter(event)">
```

This is the function that appends the `input` text to a paragraph, *sTopics*, when *Enter* is pressed, for testing purpose

```js
function checkEnter(event) {
  var sTopics;
  var eKey = event.key;
  if (eKey == "Enter") {
    sTopics = document.getElementById("selTopics");
    sTopics.innerHTML += document.getElementById("TText").value.concat("<br>");
    document.getElementById("TText").value = "";
  }
}
```

And this is the function triggered when an item is selected from the dropdown menu,

```js
function setTopic(newTopic) {
  const ke = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13
  });
  document.getElementById("TText").value = newTopic;
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("TText").dispatchEvent(ke);
}
```

I've got the *KeyboardEvent* solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937620/1988220) but, when I select an item from the D-D, all that happens is that the text gets added to the `input`, the *Enter* key is not "detected" (the text doesn't get added to the paragraph and the Input text doesn't get cleared.

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Add `,key: 'Enter'` after `keyCode:13`

Comment: @wOxxOm, spot on!! :D Thanks a mill!!! I thought the keyCode would do it. I understand now what the problem was: whereas the listener was waiting for the key "Enter" to arrive, I was sending a keyCode "13". I got the KeyboardEvent event and definition and dispatch from an example and I thought it would be/represent the same, but they are not "exactly", I needed to specify the same attribute on both places.